# Show boolean values in Handlebars

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

Trying to learn Ember JS, and I am a complete beginner.

I have an Ember JS application where a model has a boolean value. When I show this value in Handlebars, I do it like this:

```
{{#if user.active}}Yes{{else}}No{{/if}}
```

What I am not sure of is if this is the correct way to do it? Should I create a helper? Is there some other "best practice" way of doing this?

The model looks like this:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
export default DS.Model.extend({
    id: DS.attr('integer'),
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    email: DS.attr('string'),
    location: DS.attr('string'),
    active: DS.attr('boolean'),
    administrator: DS.attr('boolean')
});
```

I am thankful for all the pointers I can get :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A shorter alternative is to use the inline version of the `if` helper, like this:

```
{{if user.active 'Yes' 'No'}}
```

Let's reference the [Writing Helpers](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.10.0/templates/writing-helpers/) official documentation to implement the helper.

You can get started by running `ember generate helper is-user-active` in your terminal. Replace `is-user-active` with the name that you want.

Then, open `app/helpers/is-user-active.js` and change the code to:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export function isUserActive([user]) {
  return user.get('active') ? 'Yes' : 'No';
}

export default Ember.Helper.helper(isUserActive);
```

After saving, you can start using this helper like so: `{{is-user-active user}}`.

[edit: localization]

To support localization using `ember-i18n` (see comments), we will need to use the [i18n service](https://github.com/jamesarosen/ember-i18n/wiki/Doc:-i18n-Service) provided by the addon. In order to use it, we need to change our helper to use the [Class-based helper syntax](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.10.0/templates/writing-helpers/#toc_class-based-helpers):

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Helper.extend({
  i18n: Ember.inject.service(),

   compute([user], hash) {
    let isUserActive = user.get('active');

    if (isUserActive) {
      return this.get('i18n').t('user.active');
    } else {
      return this.get('i18n').t('user.notActive');
    }
  }
});
```

`user.active` and `user.notActive` are made up keys, you'll need to substitute for your own. The `i18n` service documentation has an example of passing data for interpolation, if necessary.

Comment: Thank you for an easy-to-understand example. Do you know if it is possible to use localization in helpers?

Comment: It is, but you might need to use the class based syntax instead. Are you already using a localization addon?

Comment: Yes, I have started to use the [ember-i18n module](https://github.com/jamesarosen/ember-i18n)

Comment: Added an example using i18n!

Comment: Thank you so much, this is of great help! Not only did it solve my problem, I learned about Class based syntax too. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

A helper would be a simple and clean solution

```
// Helper
Handlebars.registerHelper("printBool", function(b) {
  if (b) {
    return "Yes";
  } else {
    return "No";
  }
});

// Usage 
{{printBool user.active}}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you provide some example code on how to do this, or maybe point me to a tutorial on how to make a helper like this? As I said, I am a complete beginner in Ember and Handlebars :)

Comment: // Helper
    Handlebars.registerHelper("printBool", function(b) {
      if (b) {
        return "Yes";
      } else {
        return "No";
      }
    });
    
    // Usage 
    {{printBool user.active}}